# Как вывести полученный ответ в TextView?

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

Я делаю запрос на получение информации о пользователе(имя фамилия):

```
VKRequest username = VKApi.users().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS,"first_name,last_name"));
```

И как мне вывести полученный ответ в `TextView`?

Помогите пожалуйста, я ещё новичок в программировании и на `stackoverflow` впервые:)

Comment: Уточнить в чем заключается проблема? вы не знаете как полученную строку вставить в TextView или как получить эту самую строку?

Comment: @KirillStoianov, Как полученную строку вставить в TextView.

Comment: myTextView.setText("yourString");

Comment: @KirillStoianov, нет, это не совсем то, у меня есть String, и надо содержание этого string заменить на полученный ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, то вы делаете запрос на получение юзеров, тоесть в ваш  `VKRequest username` приходит список пользователей,  я полагаю что то  похожее на это:

```
response: [{
    id: 210700286,
    first_name: 'Lindsey',
    last_name: 'Stirling',
    city: {
    id: 5331,
    title: 'Los Angeles'
    },
    photo_50: 'https://pp.vk.me/...f6e/4-funfNRMwg.jpg',
    verified: 1
}]
```

Возможно ваш запрос должен выглядеть так

```
final VKRequest request = VKApi.users().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS, "first_name,last_name"));
request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
        VKApiUserFull user = ((VKList<VKApiUserFull>)response.parsedModel).get(0);

    //устанавливаем имя пользователя в TextView
    yourTextView.setText(user.first_name);
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо больше!) Разобрался, всё заработало))

Answer (score 2):

Из Request username, Вам нужно достать в String first_name и last_name
потом передать их в TextView

```
//находите textView
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.colorText); 
//устанавливаете нужный текст
textView.setText("Ваши string first_name и last_name");
```

Comment: А как достать в  String first_name и last_name?

Answer (score 1):

```
TextView tvUserName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvUserName);
tvUserName.setText("имя пользователя");
```

Answer (score 1):

У себя в приложении данные я получаю так:

```
  private void getMeInfo() {

        VKApi.users().get().executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject r = response.json.getJSONArray("response").getJSONObject(0);
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.putExtra("provider", "vkontakte");
                    intent.putExtra("access_token", access_token.accessToken);
                    intent.putExtra("uid", r.getString("id"));
                    intent.putExtra("email", "");
                    intent.putExtra("first_name", r.getString("first_name"));
                    intent.putExtra("last_name", r.getString("last_name"));

                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                } catch (JSONException ignored) {
                }
                finish();
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(VKRequest.VKProgressType progressType, long bytesLoaded, long bytesTotal) {
                super.onProgress(progressType, bytesLoaded, bytesTotal);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(VKError error) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(VkontakteActivity.this).setMessage(error.errorMessage).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void attemptFailed(VKRequest request, int attemptNumber, int totalAttempts) {
            }
        });
    }
```